# How did cosmic inflation even occur?

Tags: big-bang-theory, dark-matter, cosmological-inflation, heat, exotic-matter

I wanted to ask this question that which inflation model shall i believe?
Following below will be MY UNDERSTANDING (MAY NOT BE CORRECT) OF IT:

I read "A Brief History of Time" and in chapter 8, The origin and fate of the universe, it is written that the universe entered a "supercooled" state and temperatures dropped but the symmetry between (+was gravity also there in the unified force talked about here?) forces was maintained, and that maintenance required energy that had antigravitational effects because it gave KE to the existing particles (like it prevented gravitational collapse to occur, as a result, the universe remains stable volume/size wise). But then like any supercooled state, this state of the universe was metastable, so as soon as the energy got fully utilized in the work, the false vacuum of the universe decayed (why though?) into a more stable state and the symmetry between forces broke down, releasing energy again that would reheat the universe back to temperatures just shy of being enough for the symmetries to arise again and then the universe would just expand off continuously at a slower rate.
I have some questions regarding this:

1. Why were the forces unified at large temperatures?
2. wasnt the energy released later when the symmetries of the supercooled universe broke already used earlier in the antigravitational effects that kept the universe stable and/or ever increasing in volume against gravitational collapse? or are these two energies different?
3. Was their matter to absorb energy during the initial supercooled force symmetric universe and during the release of energy when the metastable false vacuum decayed into a stable state at the same temperature but separate forces?
4. What regarding the inflatons???? where do these fit into this model?

PLEASE HELP
and give an intuitive answer (preferably with less math)

Comment: Some of these may help https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=inflation